# Angular 2: sanitizing HTML stripped some content with div id - this is bug or feature?

Tags: security, angular, warnings, html-sanitizing

I use `<div [innerHTML]="body"></div>` to pass unescaped HTML to my template, and when I pass to `body` `div` with attribute `id`, Angular throw:

> WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
>   WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
>   WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

[See. plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/noTI3NKSBlq3W1CwrZkt?p=preview)

So why it says this? What can be dangerous `id` in `div`? Could this bug?

Comment: Here's an explanation and a possible solution to the problem [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/security#trusting-safe-values)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is because id attribute is not safe.

This is not my answer but it will answer your question : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/88973/why-do-id-attributes-need-stricter-validation

---

For `id` and `name`, these attributes are frequently used as reference points in the DOM.

**If an attacker can spoof these reference points, she may be able trick existing scripts into getting and setting values from places other than designed, which may be dangerous depending on the context that is is used**.

---

Note from me: The rest of his post talks about the name attribute, but you'll get the idea behind all this if you don't already by what's above

---

This also applies to HTML forms where `name` is used to identify the name/value pair. For example, if a website does not encode a particular form field when it is output, but since the form field is server generated and the form is protected against CSRF by the use of tokens it cannot be exploited by normal means. However, an attacker may be able to entice a user to visit a URL with a parameter that is used in `name`, containing an XSS payload to execute on submission of the form.

e.g. Normal use:

```
https://example.com/product?item_name=watch&qty=1
```

which renders a form

```html
<form>

<input type="hidden" name="watch" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="shop_name" value="Bob's Supplies" />
<input type="hidden" name="anti-csrf" value="asdjasodhoai" />

<input type="submit" value="Click here to buy" />

</form>
```

And then gets output as

```
Thank you for buying from Bob's Supplies.
```

However, an attacker could send a link to the user like so:

```
https://example.com/product?item_name=shop_name&qty=<script>alert('xss')</script>
```

As the application is correctly HTML encoding at this point it renders the form as

```
<form>

<input type="hidden" name="shop_name" value="&lt;script&gt;alert(&#039;xss&#039;)&lt;/script&gt;" />
<input type="hidden" name="shop_name" value="Bob's Supplies" />
<input type="hidden" name="anti-csrf" value="asdjasodhoai" />

<input type="submit" value="Click here to buy" />

</form>
```

This then gets output as

```
Thank you for buying from <script>alert('xss')</script>.
```

since this page doesn't HTML encode the `shop_name` parameter because it is trusted and the application framework always takes the first value in case of duplicates. Very contrived, but it was the first thing that fell into my head to demonstrate the point.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628007/angular2-innerhtml-binding-remove-style-attribute/39630507

Answer (score 100):

Simple solution is to write pipe like

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sanitizeHtml'
})
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private _sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(v:string):SafeHtml {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(v);
  }
}
```

add in your html file add pipe like

```
  <td *ngIf="i>0" [innerHTML]="entry.attributes[i] | sanitizeHtml"></td>
```

Comment: together with the answer from Karl from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007130/the-pipe-could-not-be-found-angular2-custom-pipe a good fix for this problem with the Sanitizer

Comment: @sanyooh This works well sanatizing but I get `undefined` being displayed momenteraly before my `[innerHTML]` content is display. `<div [innerHTML]="code | sanitizeHtml"></div>`

Comment: SafeHtml?  where it should be imported from

Comment: When writing the pipe don't forget to import DomSanitizer and SafeHtml. `import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

Comment: @fidev you can add a null check to your code for example. `<div [innerHTML]="user?.name | sanitizeHtml"></div>`

Comment: i added the above code in my `home.ts` and `home.html`  but it says `Template parse errors:
The pipe 'sanitizeHtml' could not be found ("`   what do i need to do ?

Comment: Getting `WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)`. There was mentioning elsewhere that this approach doesn't work inside ng-content so might be that case.

Comment: If you get pipe 'sanitizeHtml' was not found you just make a pipe and put that code there. Angular cli: ng generate pipe <pipename> and edit the pipefile.ts generated and insert code there, and it will work.

Comment: Certainly not recommended, unless you are absolutely sure that you can trust your html.

Answer (score 8):

**To mark a value as trusted, inject DomSanitizer and call one of the following methods:**

```
bypassSecurityTrustHtml
bypassSecurityTrustScript
bypassSecurityTrustStyle
bypassSecurityTrustUrl
bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl



import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

public sanitizer: DomSanitizer

[innerHtml]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content)"
```

https://angular.io/guide/security#xss

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [NgDompurify](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/ng-dompurify) library. It can sanitize your content better due DomPurify and solves all your problems with angular default sanitizer.