# Is it possible to bind dynamic html code inside angular (2+) template code with angular expressions in it?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to render dynamic HTML into an angular component. The problem is the dynamic HTML Content may have angular expressions in it and I want it to be rendered also. I have tried DomSanitizer and Component Factory Methods (links below), but I couldn't get the job done. Basically I want angular to compile template code on the go.

```
@component ({
  template : `{{ htmlCodeWithAngularExperssion }}`
)}

export class SomeComponent {
  this.htmlCodeWithAngularExperssion = `Hello, I am {{ name }} !
                      and My Hobbies are : 
                      <span *ngFor="let hob of hobbies" >{{ hob }}</span>`;

  this.name = 'Sreenivas';
  this.hobbies = ['Video Games', 'Treckking'];

 }
}
```

1. DomSanitizer Method : [Angular 2: sanitizing HTML stripped some content with div id - this is bug or feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681163/angular-2-sanitizing-html-stripped-some-content-with-div-id-this-is-bug-or-fe)
2. Component Factory : [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2)

Comment: Have a look here: https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to do anymore, as the angular compiler does not ship with the build anymore to make the build size smaller. The templates are all precompiled.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi, I have tried that. But I can only able to create component on the go, the template inside the dynamic component is pre-compiled and could not be changed

Comment: @tomvangreen There is a solution to pre-compile it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48028676/compile-dynamic-html-in-angular-4-5-something-similar-to-compile-in-angular-js. But it is not working