# How can I achieve component interpolation with ngx-translate?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I want to be able to obtain this:

```
<p>Agree with the company's <a href="#" _target="blank">Terms and Conditions</a>.</p>
```

but without placing any HTML in the translation text.

My translation file should contain the following keys:

```
{
    "agreement": "Agree with company's {tc}"
    "terms": "Terms and Conditions"
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is similar with Vue I18n's [component interpolation](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html) where I would do something like this:

```
<i18n path="agreement" tag="p">
    <a place="tc" _target="blank">{{ translate('terms') }}</a>
</i18n>
```

Is this possible with ngx-translate?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly. Is {tc} what you want to pass as the anchor tag href attribute?

Comment: No. {tc} is the placeholder for the entire <a> element.

Comment: Just to make sure: you can't or don't want to use simply something like this: <p>{{ 'agreement' | translate }} <a href="#" _target="blank">{{ 'terms' | translate }}</a></p>

Comment: Unfortunately no, because in some languages the order of words is different. That's why the 'agreement' translation should include the placeholder for the <a> element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, someone can find a better solution, but in the meantime, [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzd4a7) might work for you. Keep in mind that everything inside `setTranslation` is what you would have in your `en.json` file. I just didn't want to load it in the StackBlitz. I'm also relying on a `sanitizeHtml` that you can find inside the example. It's based on this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681163/angular-2-sanitizing-html-stripped-some-content-with-div-id-this-is-bug-or-fe/40942179#40942179).

```js
export class AppComponent  {

  private anchor;

    constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
        translateService.use('en');
        translateService.setTranslation('en', {
            HELLO: 'hello',
            AGREE: "Agree with company's {{ anchor }}",
            TC: "Terms and Conditions"
        });

        this.anchor = `<a href="#" _target="blank">${this.translateService.instant('TC')}</a>`
    }
}
```

```
<p [innerHTML]="'AGREE' | translate:{ anchor: anchor } | sanitizeHtml"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer, it seems to be a good solution.