# Angular-calendar label doesn't allow attributes in HTML label other than href

Tags: html, angular, calendar, angular9, angular-calendar

So I'm working on an application that uses the package [angular-calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar) to show calendars, but it seems to encounter a weird behavior in which I cannot see what I'm doing wrong.

I'm basically trying to add multiple attributes to an element (represented by label in code below), but none seem to work, other than href.

This is my code

```
      eAction = {
        label: `<a id='subscribe' style='margin: 10px;' href='${"/heroes/"}${hero.id}'>See hero</a>`,
        a11yLabel: "...",
        onClick: ...
      }
```

Other things that I tried:

- Only having `id` attribute doesn't, does not show the attribute in the html.
- Switching attribute postions doesn't seem to affect it.
- Switching " for ` also doesn't help: `<a id=${"Hello"} href='test'>Hello</a>` still shows in the generated HTML as `<a href="test">Hello</a>`. Same case for `<a id="Hello" href='test'>Hello</a>` and `<a id='Hello' href='test'>Hello</a>`

[There's a demo on stackblitz where you can try this yourself](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink) (line 67 or 70 in `component.ts`).

**EDIT**

I noticed a warning in the console that is related to this exact section.

[image]

So maybe it has to do with [XSS](https://angular.io/guide/security#xss). Either way my question stays the same: how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` from `@angular/core` to my component fixed it.

```
@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because id and name attributes are not safe.

More: [Angular 2: sanitizing HTML stripped some content with div id - this is bug or feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681163/angular-2-sanitizing-html-stripped-some-content-with-div-id-this-is-bug-or-fe)

For correct (and safe) solution.

HTML

```
eAction = {
        label: `<a id='subscribe' style='margin: 10px;' [href]='getActionLink()'>See hero</a>`,
        a11yLabel: "...",
        onClick: ...
      }
```

Typescript

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private _sanitilize: :DomSanitizer){...}

getActionLink(): string{
   return this._sanitilize.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("/heroes/" + this.hero.id);
}
```