# Render html tag within mat-table cell

Tags: html, angular, material-ui, tags, angular-material-table

i am trying to find a way to render an html tag
inside a mat-table cell using angular. The reason im trying to do this is because i want to
render a colored circle next of a cell value. I didnt find any working solution online so I would
really appreciate if anyone could help!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the [Angular Material Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api) for the table you will notice an extensive list of table directives that extend the respective cdk directives. The one you're looking for is **MatCellDef**.

This is a structural directive so be sure to prefix it with an asterisk (*matCellDef).

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="myColName">
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> --> insert your circle <-- {{ el.value }} </td>
</ng-container>
```

You can add anything you want inside of the mat-cell and it will be rendered there for cells in that column.

Comment: what i want to do is to render a string to html tag. currently on the table i have as a string the html tag, it doesnt translate the string to html tag @Nick

Comment: Something like: <div [innerHTML]="element.myStringHtmlData"></div> Is that what you're looking for? Plop that in the cell, don't forget to sanitize it.

Comment: innerHtml is not valid in mat table by security

Comment: Sorry I can't really help you without some context. Are you [sanitizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681163/angular-2-sanitizing-html-stripped-some-content-with-div-id-this-is-bug-or-fe) the HTML? I don't think this is specific to mat-table

Comment: i want to include a dot icon/svg/css with custom color whatever is possible to a mat cell! @Nick