# How to prevent jasmine test from failing due to "WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content, see https://g.co/ng/security#xss thrown"

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, xss, angular-dom-sanitizer

I'm writing unit tests for a component that uses [innerHTML] to display content from backend. In the browser when the component is loaded, this warning
"WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content, see https://g.co/ng/security#xss thrown" is displayed in the console, but there's nothing preventing the component from behaving normally.

However, when I write any unit test for the component, even just testing if the component created and is truthy, the test is marked as failing due to this warning.

I know that the solution to removing that warning from the component is to alter the component to use a Data Pipe utilizing the DomSanitizer class -- but I'd prefer to move forward with writing the unit tests without altering the actual component itself. Is there any way I can avoid this warning *only* manipulating the test file? Something like catching this warning and accepting it, or some other solution that could prevent this warning from failing the entire test.

Thanks!

Comment: Has been solved here! [Check Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681163/angular-2-sanitizing-html-stripped-some-content-with-div-id-this-is-bug-or-fe)

Comment: @Sagmar Appreciate the response, but I've already looked at that post. All of those comments are specific to fixing the issue within the component itself, not fixing it within a spec jasmine test file. If possible, I'd like to allow this warning in my jasmine test file and avoid altering the component