# Angular 2 Unit Test: Custom Pipe error The pipe could not be found

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I have a custom pipe called 'myPipe'. I am getting:

> The pipe 'myPipe' could not be found error

in my unit test ts. Pleas advice what to import and declare in my .spec.ts

Here is my .spec.ts

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { MyComponent } from './main-page-carousel.component';

describe('CarouselComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent ;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: you're talking about `myPipe` but your test is related to a `CarouselComponent`? you shouldn't import `myPipe` instead?

Comment: Check also this "pipe not found" entry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007130/the-pipe-could-not-be-found-angular2-custom-pipe/40770507#40770507

Answer (score 157):

You should be able to do this:

```js
import { MyPipe } from 'here put your custom pipe path';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ MyComponentUnderTesting, MyPipe ]
})
```

Comment: How can we declare it at root module? so that no need to declare in each spec file

Comment: I was confused b/c I imported the pipe into my testbed module as a provider, which would be correct if it was injected into the tsc component. However, b/c I was using it in an html file, the pipe had to imported as a declaration.

Comment: @jonuojha, did you ever find a way to declare custom pipes globally for test specs?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, and fixed it by adding the following "mock pipe" to my spec.ts:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'myPipe'})
class MockPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number): number {
        // blah blah
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then you have to add MockPipe to the TestBed configureTestingModule declarations:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ MyComponentUnderTesting, MockPipe ]
})
```

Answer (score 8):

I had almost the same pipe issue; in cases of template parse errors, you need to take two steps:

1. Import the required pipe at the start like:

   `import {{ your_pipe_name }} from '../your/pipe/location'`;
2. Add it to your declaration:

   `TestBed.configureTestingModule({ declarations: [ your_pipe ] });`

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you aliased/named your pipe but no one is answering based on this. For example, if your pipe is named `myCustomPipe` but this is different than the class name for the pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'myCustomPipe',
  pure: false
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    // ....
}
```

then in your `spec.ts` file you can import your pipe as follows or it will not be found:

```
import { MyPipe as myCustomPipe } from 'path/to/pipe';
```

and in your `beforeEach()` you need to reference the alias as both a `declaration` and  a `provider`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [ ... ],
        declarations: [ myCustomPipe, etc],
        providers: [ myCustomPipe, etc ]
    }).compilecomponents();

    // etc
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you should start something like

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MyPipe } from 'here put your custom pipe path';

describe('Pipe: MyPipe', () => {
  it('create an instance', () => {
    let pipe = new MyPipe();
    expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```