# Angular 4 template "Pipe could not be found"

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use a custom-built pipe in my `Angular 4` project. Can't figure out why the compiler doesn't recognize my pipe in the component template.

**QFormat pipe**

```
@Pipe({  name: 'qFormat'})
export class QFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {...}
```

**SharedModule**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [QFormatPipe],
    exports: [QFormatPipe]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**FeatureModule**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule],
  declarations: [MyComponent]
})
export class FeatureModule{ }
```

**MyComponent.html**

```
<div>{{someProp | qformat}}</div>
                  ^^^^^^^
```

The template throws error:

> Angular: the pipe 'qformat' could not be found

Am I missing something?

Comment: Everything looks fine, did you restart and see

Comment: @Sajeetharan I had misspelled the pipe name in the template. I should have used a capital `F` as in `qFormat`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it can't find the pipe is because you registered the pipe as 'qFormat' with a capital F but in the HTML you have 'qformat' with a lowercase f. This is why the error is occurring. Your shared module registration and import/export is completely on point. The HTML should be:

```
<div>{{someProp | qFormat}}</div>
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 8):

In my case the problem was that generating through CLI was adding pipe inside `app.module.ts` but the module of the component I was working in was different. Or in your case it could be **not registered pipe/wrongly registered pipe in module you're using** it.

**So a quick solution is:**

> Delete the pipe you've created (Don't forget to remove it from
>   app.module.ts). Then create a folder like pipes: Then generate a
>   module for it like 'ng g module pipes/pipes-common'

Then generate you pipe like 'ng g pipe myPipeExample` and now don't forget to add it

**declarations:[myPipeExamplePipe]** array and

**exports:[myPipeExamplePipe]** array

Now import this module inside the module where you want to have it working.

[This question has multiple very helpful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007130/the-pipe-could-not-be-found-angular2-custom-pipe/40770507)

Answer (score 2):

mine was as simple as just forgetting to register it to my @NgModule