# Data transformation using ionic pipe

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I try to use pipe in ionic project but can't change data, It shows some error.
please suggest a solution for this.

pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'statusupdater'
})
export class StatusUpdater {

  transform(value, args) {
    let status=value;
    if(value=='L')
    {
      status='Landed'
    }
    if(value=='A')
    {
      status='Estimated'
    }
    if(value=='C')
    {
      status='Cancelled'
    }

    return status;
  }
}
```

html:

```
<span>{{item.status | statusupdator}}</span>
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Where are you declaring the pipe?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007130/the-pipe-could-not-be-found-angular2-custom-pipe

Comment: D.Simon i declared in app.module.ts
import {StatusUpdater} from "../pipes/statusupdater";

Comment: Have you added pipe to declarations in module?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing implementing the `PipeTransform` interface.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'statusupdater'
})
export class StatusUpdater implements PipeTransform {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare it as 'statusupdatEr' but then use it as 'statusupdatOr'.