# Pipe could not be found: Angular 5 custom pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, angular-pipe

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007130/the-pipe-could-not-be-found-angular2-custom-pipe) and [this article](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b). I believe I have done everything suggested: added the pipe to a module which is shared.

However, no matter what I do I cannot get my template to find the pipe I created. My app already has a Shared Module which the other modules import, so I create the pipe and added it to the shared module:

I created it with `ng g pipe /shared/pipes/safe --flat --module shared --spec=false`

In SharedModule, I also added it to `declarations` and `providers`.

Everything runs, but it I try to use the pipe, as in:

`<iframe width="600" height="360" [src]="video.acf.youtube_url | safe: 'url'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

I just get an error

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'safe' could not be found`

The pipe itself is

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
      case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
      case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
      case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
      case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
      case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
      default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to add it under **`SharedModule`**  exports as well,

```
exports: [
   SafePipe
]
```